# No persistence exception translators found in bean factory. Cannot perform exception translation. (spring 2.1.13.RELEASE)

Tags: exception, persistence, translation

When start my project, the error comes up. It has nothing to do with hibernate, just run the project which is new created.

Comment: persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor 的主要任务是将Spring持久层的异常转向Spring标准异常，问题原因是spring boot已有替代的类，persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor只有在Spring Framework中才需要，解决方式：依赖中排除掉<exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.